# Game Maker - Turn On/Off Sound

Tags: game-maker, sound

**What I have**

I have two rooms: `rm_home` and `rm_options`. I have a sound: `snd_Bgm`. And, I have three objects: `obj_bgm`, `obj_BtnOnClicked`, and `obj_BtnOffClicked`.

**What I want is very simple**

Player can turn on/off the `snd_Bgm`.

**What I have done**

In `obj_bgm`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.sound to 1`
>
> Room Start: stop sound `snd_Bgm`; if `global.sound == 1` then play sound `snd_Bgm`

In `obj_BtnOnClicked`, I have these events:

> Left-Pressed Event: play sound `snd_Bgm`; set var `global.sound to 1`

In `obj_BtnOffClicked`, I have these events:

> Left-Pressed Event: stop sound `snd_Bgm`; set var `global.sound to 0`

I put `obj_BtnOnClicked`, and `obj_BtnOffClicked` in `rm_options`, which can be accessed from `rm_home`. Then, I put `obj_bgm` in `rm_home`.

**This is the problem**

When game start, it will show `rm_home` and plays the `snd_bgm`. I go to `rm_options`, then click the `obj_BtnOffClicked` to turn off the sound, so the sound is off. But, when I go back to `rm_home`, the sound is on again.

**What I think**

I shouldn't put `Create Event: set var global.sound to 1` in `obj_bgm`, because when `rm_home` start, it takes the value of var `global.sound` from *Create Event*. But, if I put *Create Event* in `obj_BtnOnClicked` or `obj_BtnOffClicked`, it shows a *Get Error*.

What should I do? Please explain your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that each time you enter a room, you create a new instance of obj_bgm, unless it is a persistent object. So, you are constantly setting global.sound to be 1 when you enter the room.

If it is not a persistent object, change it to be one, and it should fix the problem. (This should be as simple as checking the box that says "persistent" to the right of the the events window.)

Comment: It works! I don't know about persistent object before. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. We all start somewhere.